# Dart split / compress Lists

Tags: list, flutter, dart

This is the code for my list:

```
      Future<List<Map>> queryDb() async {
    List localList;
    final db = await database;
    final allRows = await db.query(TABLE_FAVORITE);
    localList = allRows.toList(growable: true);
    localList.removeWhere((item) => item[COLUMN_ISFAVORITE] == 0);
    publicFavoriteList = localList;
    print(localList);
    return localList;
}
```

whenever it gets called it prints:

```
[{id: 0, isFavorite: 1}, {id: 1, isFavorite: 1}, {id: 2, isFavorite: 1}, {id: 4, isFavorite: 1}]
```

How can I "cut" this to

```
[{0}, {1}, {2}, {4}]
```

Comment: I think it can not be like that. Because {} curly bracket needs key and value.

Comment: @KuKu `{}` can be either a map (key and value) or a set (just value). Either way, I think OP just wants a list of those values, not to have each value wrapped in a completely redundant set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` to extract the values from the inner `Map` objects:

```dart
var localValues = localList.map((o) => o['id'] as int).toList();
print(localVales);

// Prints: [0, 1, 2, 4]
```